# How do I successfully convert a 32b image to 8b?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I have an input image of type CV_32UC3 RGB Mat that I would like to convert to CV_8UC3. I have tried using the convertTo method as follows:

```
img.convertTo(dst, CV_8UC3, 0.00390625)
```

However, the resulting image is completely black.

My question is, how do I successfully convert a 32b 3 channel image to 8b?

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. First you talk about `CV_32UC3 -> CV_8UC3`. Later it's `CV_32UC4 -> CV_8UC4`. Then in the answer it becomes floating point instead of integer. So, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That inconsistency has no baring on the question, which is clear from the subject line. To avoid confusion I have edited the description.

Comment: IMHO it does. `CV_32UC3` is different from `CV_32FC3`, one being `int32_t`, the other `float`. Floating point images usually have range of intensities 0.0-1.0. In an integer image this sort of range would mean only 2 colors. If your input data is really 32 bit integers, what is the actual range of the values in there? 0 .. (2^32)-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your scale is backwards. If you want to scale from a floating point image (0-1 values) to 8 bit you need to use 255 as your scale factor.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I discovered this just as you posted!